# How to find members who have more than X years of total membership

Tags: civimember

What's the best way to calculate the total number of years/days that a contact has been a member?

For example, say I want to find people who have been a member for more than 10 years, taking gaps into consideration.

I was thinking of a combination of the "civicrm_log_membership" table with a custom field, or maybe the [summary-fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension. By having it in a custom field, it would be easy to expose to the search/reports, and it could be regularly updated using a Scheduled Job.

Comment: i like the sound of Summary Fields approach

Comment: In this case are you assuming if there is a gap this means there is a new membership? So this would be the sum of the duration of each membership on a contact that doesn't overlap?

Comment: I always assumed that a gap would create a new membership, but a colleague insists that this is not always the case. I need to double-check (I would consider it a bug!).